# Devise: Links don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

for my web app I'm using devise for the user authentication. Alas the app
doesn't return the sign in(or sign up) page, when I click on the links, but
the root page. Maybe somebody can help? Thanks!

routes.rb:

```
root to: 'static#home'
devise_for :users
devise_for :user, :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout", :sign_up => "register" }
```

_header.html.erb:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
     <div class="container">
       <%= link_to "Kung Pao", '#', id: "logo" %>
       <nav>
         <ul class="nav pull-right">
           <li><%= link_to "Start", root_path %></li>
           <li><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %></li>
           <li><%= link_to "Registrierung", new_user_registration_path %></li>
       </ul>
     </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

rake routes:

```
            root        /                        static#home
        new_user_session GET    /login(.:format)         devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /login(.:format)         devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /logout(.:format)        devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /                        devise/registrations#create
`enter code here`   new_user_registration GET    /register(.:format)      devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /                        devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /                        devise/registrations#destroy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your config/routes.rb to be:

```
root to: 'static#home'
devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout", :sign_up => "register" }
resources :users
```

You're setting path names for "user" but devise is looking for the pluralized resource name, which you define with no path.